# How to validate Spring Data JPA Queries on Startup?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Given a Spring Data JPA Repository like so.

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Product> {


    @Query("select p from Product p where p.attributes[?1] = ?2")
    List<Product> findByAttributeAndValue(String attribute, String value);
}
```

How do I get Spring Data JPA to validate each of these queries at startup. For example when I use named queries with hibernate and the query is syntactically incorrect or property name is wrong hibernate complains.

Can spring data be configured to validate queries on start-up?

Comment: You don't want to run your queries without a controlling logic. Imagine you have a `delete from Product` method. Make tests.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch I just want the quries validated without running them, if a query refers to a non existent property, or entity, or has a syntax error that can't be parsed its good to know at satrtup.

Comment: @ams did not ask to run queries on startup but to *validate* them. If the query contains invalid JPQL or entity/property names that do not map to your code then you want to get fast-fail behaviour so on startup of the server an exception will tell you that your Query is invalid. BTW: hibernate does NOT do what you are assuming to validate named queries. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565706/are-hibernate-named-queries-precompiled-in-the-true-sense/27574444

Answer (score 3):

Rather than validating this at startup, I suggest that you create a test for this that can be executed by your continues integration server. Since you are already using Spring, it is very simple to create an [Embedded Database](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support) that you can initialize with known test data.

Create two files `schema.sql` which is the actual production data schema, and `test-data.sql` which contains some known test data. Next, create a separate test application context that :

```
<beans ...>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.repositories" />

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- more beans -->
</beans>
```

or Java based configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public void EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(H2).addScript("schema.sql").addScript("test-data.sql").build();

    // more beans
}
```

Next, you create a test for your `ProductRepository`:

```
@ContextConfiguration([reference to your xml or Java application context])
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@Transactional
public class ProductRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void findProductByAttributeAndValue() {
        List<Product> actual = repository.findByAttributeAndValue("attr", "val");

        // add assertions that 'actual' contains the expected data from the test-data.sql
    }
}
```

The addition of `@Transactional` to the test class will cause the database to automatically rollback after each test method has completed. Consequently, all test will have the same database state (as specified by the `test-data.sql`) even if repository write operations are executed within a test.

Comment: I already have a pretty good test suite but it takes a while to run :) would prefer a way to just syntax check the queries at start-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method decorated with `@PostCreate` annotation on your bean and invoke the repository method so any exceptions will happen immediately. It is cumbersome if you have many.

Probably a more appropriate method is to unit tests those repository methods.

Comment: and also, just calling the methods won't be enough, because if the result is null, there may be still potential casting exceptions.